# Testing semi-parametric versus parametric model

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, nonparametric, semiparametric

I am estimating a (semi)parametric and a parametric model for a panel data set, and I want to test the functional form by applying the method proposed by [Henderson et al. (2008, p.266–267)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S030440760800016X). In particular, given the two models:

$$
\begin{aligned}
Y &= X^T\beta + Z^T\gamma + u\quad(\textrm{parametric})\\
Y &= X^T\beta + \theta(Z) + u\quad(\textrm{semi-parametric})
\end{aligned}
$$

They use $H_0$ to denote the null hypothesis of the linear regression model, against $H_1$, the corresponding alternative is the semiparametric model. Letting $\tilde{\beta}, \tilde{\gamma}$ represent consistent estimates of the parameters from the parametric model and $\hat{\beta}, \hat{\gamma}$ represent consistent estimates of the parameters from the semi-parametric model, the test statistic used in the paper for for testing $H_0$ is:

$$
I = \left[X^T\tilde{\beta}+Z^T\tilde{\gamma}-
X^T\hat{\beta}-\hat{\theta}(Z)\right]^2
$$

Under $H_0$, $I$ converges to 0 in probability, while it converges to a positive constant under $H_1$. Therefore, the statistic $I$ can be used to detect whether $H_0$ is true or not. However, given some problems with the asymptotical distribution of $I$, the authors propose to compute its empirical distribution by resampling $u$, the residuals, $n$ times, using those residuals to generate $n$ new $Y$s and then re-estimating both models $n$ times. By this way it is possible to obtain $n$ estimates of $I^*$ and its empirical distribution which should be approximating the null distribution of $I$. Therefore it can be used to detect whether $H_0$ holds.

My problem is in the interpretation of the results of the test. I reasoned as follows: I plotted the empirical distribution of $I^*$ which, in my case, has mean > 0. Therefore what I did was to verify *where*  the $I$ statistic lies. This is what I obtain:

[image: Empirical distribution and test]

where `I.BB.IVO` is my $I$. Can I say that $I$ belongs to the empirical distribution (since it is not in the rejection zone) with mean `> 0`, therefore the null hypothesis is rejected?

Is there any other alternative of doing the job?